# Importing .mat file to pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using `pgfplots` to create figures, and I have a (large) set of simulation data generated from `Matlab`. It is in the `.mat` format. The data are of the form (two column)

```
(1,0.2)

(1,0.3)

...

(1,0.2)

...

(2,0.4)

(2,0.1)

...
```

A scatter plot in `pgfplots` would be appropriate. I want to directly importing this file using `pgfplots`. Unfortunately, the following code seems not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[scatter]
table{test.mat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there anyone know how to import these data ? Since the size is a little bit large, it is not possible to copy every sample into the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "two columns"? The data in your file have the parenthesis or not?

Comment: @Red No parenthesis. For instance, it is a 100 * 2 data set. The first column of the first 10 rows is 1, and the first column of the 11 to 20 rows is 2, etc.

Comment: What error do you get? I made a file `test.mat` with two rows, the first is "1 0.4" and the second is "1 0.5" and your code gives me no error

Comment: @Red The compiler says "Text line contains an invalid character", and this error also appears in the simplest case, as the example you tried.

Comment: Please edit your question adding the first rows of your `test.mat` file **exactly** as they appear in your file.

Comment: @Red matlab uses binary compression for `.mat` files and TeX can't read binary. You can use `save('myfile.txt', 'myvariablename', '-ascii','-double');` in matlab to save it as a readable `.txt` file.

Comment: @percusse ok, sorry but I don't use matlab and from the question was not clear that the data are in binary format :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is due to the fact that `.mat` file is a binary format and TeX can't read binary. I don't know how it can be made possible to read binary format from a file but a rather more convenient way is to store the arrays in a tall matrix as columns.

Suppose you have the data columns a,b,c with equal length (otherwise pad the missing entries with NaN or Inf such that pgfplots can discard it). This can be done in matlab via

```
Mymatrix = [a b c];
save('myfile.txt', 'Mymatrix', '-ascii','-double');
```

This would save the arrays in a plain text format with no headers. I didn't check if full path is supported in the file name field but should be possible.

In general, I would recommend staying away from including column names to the `Mymatrix`. Because matlab is a great software.

Comment: I mean including column names inside matlab. You can always edit the file and add them externally.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Matlab versions, the recommended way is to generate a table from the array and write the table to a CSV file. The table has a header row that contains the column names and is also written to the CSV. See [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/281150-writing-a-matrix-with-header-into-a-csv-file)